# Trying to get a function as a user input but is not working, doesn't accept the String to Double

Tags: java

I need help with getting a user's input which is a function like 2*x or 2/x etc... I originally tried this by getting a String value from the user and then converting that into a double but Java doesn't like this for some reason. I checked line 56 in the error and it's when I convert the String to a double.

```
System.out.println("What is the formula?");
    formula = keyboard.nextLine();

double newFormula = Double.valueOf(formula);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input      string: "2*x"
at    sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
at newpackage.CurveArea.main(CurveArea.java:56)
```

Comment: What double value were you expecting would be assigned to newFormula?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trying to cast the String to a Double, but it is not Double because it contains non numeric chars. For getting the 2 out of the input String you can try something like this.

```
    String formula = "2/x";
    double newFormula = 0d;
    for (String mathSign : new String[] { "/", "*" }) {
        if (formula.contains(mathSign)) {
            newFormula = Double.valueOf(formula.substring(0, formula.indexOf(mathSign)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newFormula);
```

In the if-statement can also the mathSign detected.